# Check whether a list of hexadecimal values is sequential or not

Tags: python, list, hex, iteration, sequence

Want a function / statement, to check whether all the values of `mylist` are sequential or not, which is **hexadecimal** list.
For example:

```
def checkmylist(mylist):
    #code returns True or False


mylist1 = ['03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']
mylist2 = ['03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']

checkmylist(mylist1)
#expected to returns pass
checkmylist(mylist2)
#expected to returns fail
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def checkmylist(mylist):
    it = (int(x, 16) for x in mylist)
    first = next(it)
    return all(a == b for a, b in enumerate(it, first + 1))
```

With the first statement we convert the hex numbers to a generator of integers. With `next(it)` we take the first element of the generator. Then we enumerate the rest of the elements starting the numbering from `first + 1`. We conclude that we have a sequential list if the numbering of each element is the same as the element itself.

Comment: Need to add one more logic in the above function, my sequence would be limited, for example,  `00 to 10` or `00 to 0a(Hex)`, what could be the efficient way to do that. my function should return `true` for `mylist = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a','00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a']` too.

Answer (score 4):

One hack to do it is. This finds the total elements in the list. As you mention that it has t be sequential, the last element must be length of the list more than the first element.

```
>>> def checkmylist(l):
...     a = [int(i,16) for i in sorted(set(l))]
...     return (len(a) == (a[-1]-a[0]+1))
... 
>>> checkmylist(mylist1)
True
>>> checkmylist(mylist2)
False
>>> checkmylist(['2', '2', '4'])
False
```

Comment: You assume that the sequence is ordered

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Add a `a.sort()` before the return statement! It is easy as that. (The OP however does not mention that he needs that) ... :)

Comment: What about [2, 2, 4] ? It will return True.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor This solves both the flaws that you pointed out! Thank you :)

Comment: @JuniorCompressor: It's fine to assume the list is ordered because if it's not then the elements in it are not sequential, so the `sorted()` call Bhargav added isn't really necessary — besides that, it's sorting the values in the list wrong (lexicographically not numerically: i.e. `sorted(['11', '20', '130'])` gives `['11', '130', '20']`).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `iter` to create an iterator of your list (from second index to end) and then use `all` function to check if you have a sequence, note that `int(next(it),16)` (or as a more efficient way as mentioned in comment use `functools.partial(int, base=16)`)will convert your string to integer with base 16 then you can do operation on them :

```
>>> import functools
>>> int16 = functools.partial(int, base=16)
>>> def checker(li):
...    it=iter(li[1:])
...    return all(int16(next(it))-int16(i)==1 for i in li[:-1])
```

Demo:

```
mylist1 = ['03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']
mylist2 = ['03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']
>>> checker(mylist1)
True
>>> checker(mylist2)
False
```

Comment: You could optimize this a little bit more by using `int16 = functools.partial(int, base=16)` and then using `int16(x)` calls instead of `int(x, 16)`.

Comment: I like that this is adaptable to increments other than 1

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist1 = ['03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']
mylist2 = ['03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']

def checkmylist(li):
    start=int(li[0],16)
    for e in li[1:]:
        a=int(e,16)
        if a==start+1:
            start=a
        else:
            return False
    return True


assert checkmylist(mylist1)==True
#expected to returns pass
assert checkmylist(mylist2)==False
#expected to returns fail
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @JuniorCompressor but using a list comprehension,
your base construct would be:

```
bool_match_to_myList = [1 if int(i, 16) else 0 for i in mylist]
```

You could check to see if that is true/false easy enough:

```
myList_is_sequential = sum([1 if int(i, 16) else 0 for i in mylist]) < 1
```

Or you can find the indexes where it is off (not sequential) with the help of numpy

```
import numpy as np
bool_match_to_myList_np = np.array([1 if int(i, 16) else 0 for i in mylist])
np.where(bool_match_to_myList == 0)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using the "power" of Pandas:

```
def is_sequential(mylist):
    serie = pd.Series(mylist).apply(lambda x: int(x,16))
    return (serie.diff() > 1).sum() == 0
```

- Transform the mylist variables in a int Series
- Use the diff() function, to get the difference between the last and the current value
- Sum all values more than 1 (the step that we wanted), so if the sum() is equal 0, all values are sequential

```py
is_sequential(mylist1) # returns True
is_sequential(mylist2) # returns False
```

Comment: nice! to make it more robust and include cases such as [1,2,3,0] (where the diff will show -3 at the end and will fail the "> 1" condition) you need to add abs() after the diff():
`return (serie.diff().abs() > 1).sum() == 0`