# Python: Check whether the list is in sequential or not | End of the list is defined

Tags: python, list, hex, sequence, enumerate

My function is something like this, [thanks to this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885455/python-check-whether-list-is-sequential-or-not)
which is to check whether all the values of mylist are sequential or not, which is hexadecimal list. For example:

```
mylist1 = ['03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']
mylist2 = ['03', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']

def checkmylist(mylist):
    it = (int(x, 16) for x in mylist)
    first = next(it)
    return all(a == b for a, b in enumerate(it, first + 1))


checkmylist(mylist1)
#expected to returns pass
checkmylist(mylist2)
#expected to returns fail
```

But i need one more logic to my function which should check the list even though last value of the list is known, for example,

```
00 to 10 | 00 to 0a(Hex)
```

Here its already known that **10** is the last value, that moment my function should re-initialize the counter what could be the efficient way to do that. my function should return true for limited set of values.

```
mylist = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a','00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a']

checkmylist(mylist)
#Expected True
```

Comment: Are the values always going to start/restart from zero in this case? Or is something like `['08', '09', '0a','08', '09', '0a']` also expected to return `True`?

Comment: list may start from any value, but restart will be from zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with a restart from zero using the modulus operator:

```
mylist = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a',
          '00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a']

def checkmylist(mylist, end=10):
    end += 1
    it = (int(x, 16) for x in mylist)
    first = next(it)
    return all(a % end == b for a, b in enumerate(it, first + 1))

checkmylist(mylist) # returns True
```

For known ending values other than 10, you'll need to use the second parameter of the function (e.g. `checkmylist(mylist, end=14)`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `==` operator to check if the sorted list is equal to the original.

```
# list is not in order
mylist = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a','00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a']

# list is in order
mylist2 = ['03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0a', '0b', '0c','0d', '0e', '0f']

sorted(mylist) == mylist # returns False
sorted(mylist2) == mylist2 # returns True
```

Comment: My question is to check whether **mylist** is sequential or not, where my list is very finite list, and again my list starts from the beginning.

Comment: @zachgates this answer has nothing to do with what's being asked.

Comment: I can't understand why @zachgates' answer is wrong. It seems that you are trying to see if a list is sorted. Is that right?